# Guava ImmutableList copyOf vs Builder

Tags: java, guava

I was wondering which is more efficient and why?

1)

```
List<Blah> foo;
...
return ImmutableList.copyOf(foo);
```

or

2)

```
List<Blah> foo;
...
return new ImmutableList.Builder<Blah>().addAll(foo).build();
```

Comment: Have you identified this as your performance bottleneck? Because unless you have a **specific** reason why you care about the efficiency of this, you should ignore that aspect for now and use the more readable one (i.e. the first one).

Comment: I was just curious before I started using Guava in my project.  I wasn't sure which was the 'correct' way

Comment: If there's a simple single-method-call-way that does exactly what you want and a object-construction-and-two-method-calls-way to do (kind of) the same thing, then I'd choose the simpler one each time.

Comment: @user973479 To even have the top question on your mind be which one is more efficient is misguided. If through some freak of nature the single method call were less efficient, that would just be a bug someone would eventually fix anyway.

Comment: It is NOT misguided to want to understand what is more efficient and how the library works. It is only misguided if you prefer the harder to read one due to performance without having a good reason to care about the performance in context.  The question is "what is more efficient and why" not "which should I use".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you should use builder here:

- `ImmutableList.copyOf` is much more readable than making a `Builder` in this case,
- `Builder` doesn't infer generic type and you have to specify type by
  yourself when used as one-liner,
- *(from docs)* `ImmutableList.copyOf` [does good magic](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html#copyOf%28java.util.Collection%29) when invoked with another immutable collection (*attempts to avoid actually copying the data when it is safe to do so*),
- *(from source)* `Builder#addAll` invokes `addAll` on previously created `ArrayList` while `copyOf` avoids creating any list for zero- and one-element collections (returns empty immutable list and singleton immutable list respectively),
- *(from source)* `copyOf(Collection)` instance doesn't create temporary `ArrayList` (`copyOf(Iterable)` and `copyOf(Iterator)` does so),
- *(from source)* moreover, `Builder#build` invokes `copyOf` on previously internally populated `ArrayList`, what brings you to your question - why use `Builder` here, when you have `copyOf`?

P.S. Personally I use `ImmutableList.builder()` static factory instead of `new ImmutableList.Builder<Blah>()` constructor - when assigned to a `Builder<Blah>` variable the first infers generic type while the latter doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Builder allows you to add stuff. I.e. if you need to add another object it might be easier to do with the Builder pattern:

```
ImmutableList<SomeModel> newModelObjects = new ImmutableList.Builder<SomeModel>()
    .addAll(getModelObjects()).add(newModelObject).build();
```

As opposed to:

```
ArrayList<SomeModel> list = new ArrayList<>(getModelObjects());
list.add(newModelObject);
ImmutableList<SomeModel> newModelObjects = ImmutableList.copyOf(list);
```