# Guava ImmutableSet: Builder vs. of?

Tags: java, collections, set, guava, immutability

The [Javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html) for `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet` suggests that there are two ways to create instances of `ImmutableSet<E>` from elements of type `E` (e.g. `E e1` and `E e2`) that are not already in a collection (i.e. ignoring the `copyOf` method to create from existing collection):

1. **The "of" method:**

   ```
   ImmutableSet<E> set = ImmutableSet.of(e1, e2);
   ```
2. **Builder**:

   ```
   ImmutableSet<E> set = new ImmutableSet.Builder<E>().add(e1).add(e2).build();
   ```

Both methods use `ImmutableSet.Builder#construct` in the end but **which one should I prefer?**

Comment: As a third option, you could also use `ImmutableSet.<E>builder()` instead of invoking the ctor directly. Personally, I'd use the `of(e1, e2)` form, since it is simply more concise.

Comment: Don't even think about using `Builder`, when you don't have to. It's strictly longer, less readable, and produces garbage. Not bad, but there's no advantage. Obviously, there are cases when you need the builder and then go for it.

Comment: See also [this question, comments, and my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517228/guava-immutablelist-copyof-vs-builder).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It completely depends upon how you're going to build `ImmutableSet`. If you've all the elements available at one place, then directly use `of(E...)` method. That would certainly be shorter.

But if somehow, you're getting elements from different places, that would mean, your object state is not finalized at one place, but after accumulating data on the flow. Then you will have to go with `Builder` way. Create a `Builder`, and keep on adding elements as and when you get. And then when you're done, just call `build()` to get `ImmutableSet`.

Comment: By the way, if you look at Guava's [source code](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.java) you'll notice that `Builder.build()` calls `copyOf` which calls the `of()` methods for the simplest cases (0, 1 element), so the two constructs are effectively equivalent and you end up with the same set.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta Yeah, the ultimate result is the same, as OP already mentioned. It's just the way to reaching there that differs :)